# How to check if IWorkbook object can be constructed from file stream?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I use NPOI library to read xlsx and xls files.

I have this code:

```
IWorkbook workBook = null;
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(path);
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    if (fileExtension == ".xls")
        workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
        workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
}
```

And it's work perfect.
But the problem that `path` to excel file not always has extension (.xls or .xlsx) in his name.

So I need to check if `fs` suitebale  for `HSSFWorkbook()` or for `XSSFWorkbook()`

Any idea how can I check it without extension of file?

Comment: did not tested it, but doesn't NPOI throws any exception while opening lets say *.xlsx like HSSFWorbook?

Answer (score 2):

```
            IWorkbook workBook = null;
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(path);

            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                workBook = WorkbookFactory.Create(fs);
            }
```

WorkbookFactory.Create() method constructs IWorkbook according to fileStreem parameter builded from xls or xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

Applying file header info from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures we can use something like this:

```
public static class FormatRecognizer
{
    public static Boolean IsZipFile(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(stream));

        var zipHeader = new Byte[]
        {
            0x50, 0x4B, 0x03, 0x04
        };

        var streamBytes = GetBytesAndRestore(stream, zipHeader.Length);
        return streamBytes.SequenceEqual(zipHeader);
    }


    public static Boolean IsOffice2003File(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(stream));

        var officeHeader = new Byte[]
        {
            0xD0, 0xCF, 0x11, 0xE0, 0xA1, 0xB1, 0x1A, 0xE1,
        };

        var streamBytes = GetBytesAndRestore(stream, officeHeader.Length);
        return streamBytes.SequenceEqual(officeHeader);
    }


    private static IEnumerable<Byte> GetBytesAndRestore(Stream stream, Int32 bytesCount)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(stream));

        var position = stream.Position;
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.Default, leaveOpen: true))
            {
                return reader.ReadBytes(bytesCount);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Position = position;
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
private static void PrintFormatInfo(String path)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File at '{0}'", path);
    using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        PrintFormatInfo(stream);
    }
}

private static void PrintFormatInfo(Stream stream)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Is office 2003 = {0}", FormatRecognizer.IsOffice2003File(stream));
    Console.WriteLine("Is zip file (possibly xlsx) = {0}", FormatRecognizer.IsZipFile(stream));
}
```

...

```
PrintFormatInfo("1.txt");
PrintFormatInfo("1.xls");
PrintFormatInfo("1.xlsx");
```

It is not absolutely reliable, because `IsZipFile` will return true for simple zip archive, and `IsOffice2003File` will also succeed for doc, ppt, etc.

But it is the simplest solution I can think of. And anything more correct will require more deeper knowledge of file formats, that may or may not be what you require.